# How to make dhclient run when wlan0 is brought back up (but already has an old address)

Tags: dhcp, wpa-supplicant, wlan, dhclient, devuan

With the following configuration on Devuan Chimaera Linux:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        pre-up /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
        post-down /usr/bin/killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
network={
    ssid="MySSID"
    psk="redacted"
}   
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
```

dhclient only runs when the interface first comes up.

If I use `ifconfig wlan0 down`, the IP address is retained while down and `ifconfig wlan0 up` brings the interface back up without running dhclient.

Unfortunately I have a custom /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/wlan0-routes which adds custom routes, calculated from the default route provided by dhclient.

When I bring wlan0 down, the custom routes are lost, as expected.

When I bring wlan0 up, dhclient does not run and so the custom routes are not re-added.

---

Update:

There seems to be a difference in the behaviour of `ifconfig wlan0 down` (which caused this) and `ifdown wlan0`.

```
root@demo:~# ifconfig wlan0 down
root@demo:~# ip addr show wlan0 
9: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:8e:4c:f6:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.98.196/24 brd 192.168.98.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 7130sec preferred_lft 7130sec

root@demo5:~# ifconfig wlan0 up
...
root@demo5:~# ifdown wlan0
root@demo5:~# ip addr show wlan0 
9: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:8e:4c:f6:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

When I use `ifdown wlan0` instead of `ifconfig wlan0 down` `dhclient` is called when I bring the interface up, and everything works as it ought.

What is the difference between `ifconfig wlan0 down` and `ifdown wlan0`?

Comment: You could adapt my `net-o-matic` script. I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quoting from man:

> the ifup and ifdown commands may be used to configure (or, respec-
> tively, deconfigure) network interfaces based on interface definitions
> in the files /etc/sysconfig/network and
> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<configuration>

while

> Ifconfig is used to configure the kernel-resident network
> interfaces.  It is used at boot time to set up interfaces as
> necessary.  After that, it is usually only needed when debugging
> or when system tuning is needed.

ifconfig is part of the net-tools (networking utilities) https://net-tools.sourceforge.io/

i think it's kind of an obsolete and deprecated tool replaced by iproute2 https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2

Answer (score 0):

From https://access.redhat.com/solutions/27166

What is the difference between 'ifconfig up eth0' and 'ifup eth0'?

Resolution:

An "ifconfig" command and "ifup" or "ifdown" command can activate network interfaces. "ifconfig" directly controls network interfaces, however "ifup" or "ifdown" executes "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-" or "ifdown-" scripts. The scripts use an ip command.

"ifconfig" and "ip" commands use ioctl() to activate or deactivate network interfaces. "ifconfig" flags network interfaces 'IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING', however "ip" flags that 'IFF_UP'.

An "ifconfig up eth0" activates eth0 but does not setup IP addresses, however an "ifup eth0" setup IP addresses or other options based by an ifcfg-eth0, because the "ifup" uses an "ifup-eth*" script.

The ifup command will also configure any static routes that are configured in the network-scripts directory. The ifconfig command will not.